# Check-box remains checked up after test and impacts another tests

Tags: webdriver

I have created a test case where I shall enter details for a deal to be scheduled for a future date and time. I have a pop up which is listing all existing deals having check boxes for selecting one of them independently. I could create and run the test case successfully only once but on further executions the first check box is always getting selected.

```
//steps to click on a check box 

new WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'CAR')]")));

String s=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'CAR')]")).getAttribute("id");

int number=Integer.parseInt(s.split("_")[3]);

String chkboxid="AdminMainContent_grdDealDetails_chkSelect_"+number;

new WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id(chkboxid)));

driver.findElement(By.id(chkboxid)).click();


//click on ok button
new WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("AdminMainContent_lbtnOkGrid")));
driver.findElement(By.id("AdminMainContent_lbtnOkGrid")).click();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solved issue using below code. The issue was with a for loop that I had used to iterate through all check box ids and if the page doesn't have it will click on next button. Actually I had misplaced the click on next button.

```
for (int page = 1; page <= Integer.parseInt(totaPage); page++) {
    String dealTitle;

    String dealtitleCheck = s.getCell(2, 4).getContents().trim();

// {

    System.out.println("current page number is)" + page);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //System.out.println("I=" + i);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        // get the list of all available names

        dealTitle = driver.findElement(
        By.id("AdminMainContent_grdDealDetails_lblTitle_" + i)).getAttribute("innerHTML").trim();

        System.out.println("dealTitle"+dealTitle);

        // getting the id of car from excel
        // String dealtitleCheck = s.getCell(2, 4).getContents();

        System.out.println("dealtitleCheck="+dealtitleCheck+"dealTitle="+dealTitle);

        boolean stat = dealTitle.equals(dealtitleCheck);

        System.out.println("equal status="+stat);

        if (dealTitle.equals(dealtitleCheck)) {

            // System.out.println("you got it in"+i);
            // getting id of check box to select
            String chkboxid = "AdminMainContent_grdDealDetails_chkSelect_" + i;

            // waiting
            new WebDriveWait(driver, 100)
                .until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                .id(chkboxid)));

            // click on the check box for specific deal title
            // obtained from excel
            driver.findElement(By.id(chkboxid)).click();

            //click on ok button
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("AdminMainContent_lbtnOkGrid")));
            driver.findElement(By.id("AdminMainContent_lbtnOkGrid")).click();

            break;
        }//end of if condition

    }//end of for inner loop
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
        .id("AdminMainContent_PagingCntrlDealSchedule_lbtnNext")));

    driver.findElement(
        By.id("AdminMainContent_PagingCntrlDealSchedule_lbtnNext"))
    .click();

}//end of for outer loop
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the test getting executed further? In a loop?
Is number and chkboxid re-generated with each execution?

Check that the id for each checkbox are what you are expecting for each execution.

Comment: Thanks lars for your comment.Well i got issue solved.The issue was with a for loop that i had used to iterate through all check box id and if the page doesnt have it will click on next button.Actually i had misplaced the click on next button.

Comment: Cool. When you have a chance then mark your answer as the correct one.